# How To Replace Some Characters With Asterisks

Tags: php

I have a simple task to do with PHP, but since I'm not familiar with Regular Expression or something... I have no clue what I'm going to do.

what I want is very simple actually...

let's say I have these variables :

```
$Email = 'john@example.com'; // output : ****@example.com
$Email2 = 'janedoe@example.com'; // output : *******@example.com
$Email3 = 'johndoe2012@example.com'; // output : ***********@example.com

$Phone = '0821212121'; // output : 082121**** << REPLACE LAST FOUR DIGIT WITH *
```

how to do this with PHP? thanks.

Comment: Comprehensive advice on this topic: [Hint or partially hide email address with stars (*) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43904214/2943403)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll need a specific function for each. For mails:

```
function hide_mail($email) {
    $mail_segments = explode("@", $email);
    $mail_segments[0] = str_repeat("*", strlen($mail_segments[0]));

    return implode("@", $mail_segments);
}

echo hide_mail("example@gmail.com");
```

For phone numbers

```
function hide_phone($phone) {
    return substr($phone, 0, -4) . "****";
}

echo hide_phone("1234567890");
```

And see? Not a single regular expression used. These functions don't check for validity though. You'll need to determine what kind of string is what, and call the appropriate function.

Answer (score 2):

For e-mails, this function preserves first letter:

```
function hideEmail($email)
{
    $parts = explode('@', $email);
    return substr($parts[0], 0, min(1, strlen($parts[0])-1)) . str_repeat('*', max(1, strlen($parts[0]) - 1)) . '@' . $parts[1];
}

hideEmail('hello@domain.com'); //  h****@domain.com
hideEmail('hi@domain.com');    //  h*@domain.com
hideEmail('h@domain.com');     //  *@domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried for a single-regex solution but don't think it's possible due to the variable-length asterisks. Perhaps something like this:

```
function anonymiseString($str)
{
  if(is_numeric($str))
  {
     $str = preg_replace('/^(\d*?)\d{4}$/', '$1****');
  }
  elseif(($until = strpos($str, '@')) !== false)
  {
     $str = str_repeat('*', $until) . substr($str, $until + 1);
  }
  return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I create one function to do this, works fine for me. i hope help.

```
function ofuscaEmail($email, $domain_ = false){

    $seg = explode('@', $email);
    $user = '';
    $domain = '';

    if (strlen($seg[0]) > 3) {
        $sub_seg = str_split($seg[0]);
        $user .= $sub_seg[0].$sub_seg[1];
        for ($i=2; $i < count($sub_seg)-1; $i++) { 
            if ($sub_seg[$i] == '.') {
                $user .= '.';
            }else if($sub_seg[$i] == '_'){
                $user .= '_';
            }else{
                $user .= '*';
            }
        }
        $user .= $sub_seg[count($sub_seg)-1];
    }else{
        $sub_seg = str_split($seg[0]);
        $user .= $sub_seg[0];
        for ($i=1; $i < count($sub_seg); $i++) { 
            $user .= ($sub_seg[$i] == '.') ? '.' : '*';
        }
    }

    $sub_seg2 = str_split($seg[1]);
    $domain .= $sub_seg2[0];
    for ($i=1; $i < count($sub_seg2)-2; $i++) { 
        $domain .= ($sub_seg2[$i] == '.') ? '.' : '*';
    }

    $domain .= $sub_seg2[count($sub_seg2)-2].$sub_seg2[count($sub_seg2)-1];

    return ($domain_ == false) ? $user.'@'.$seg[1] : $user.'@'.$domain ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Output: a******@gmail.com

```
$email = str_replace(substr($old_email, 1, strlen(explode("@", $old_email)[0])-1), "**********", $old_email);
```

This is a quick fix to the question above;
It ensures just the first character of the email address as the extension shows up.
You can increase or reduce the number of asterisks depending

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.