# Replace last 4 with asterisks in PHP

Tags: php

Hi there i am trying to hide the customers name and i wants to hide only the last 4 with asterisks currently i have this code but it hides the entire name after 4 digits but thats not what i want

```
$arr[$idx]['consignee']  = $row['consignee'];
```

i managed to hide the name using this code below but it hides all after 4

```
            $arr[$idx]['consignee'] = '1' > 0 ?
                                    sub_str($row['consignee'], '5') : $row['consignee'];
```

Any sample or suggestion please.

Comment: Some advice on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43904214/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
 $arr[$idx]['consignee'] = preg_replace('/.{4}$/', '****',  $arr[$idx]['consignee']);
```

Try it [here online](https://regex101.com/r/N34Gad/1)

OR substr ( for those that think regx is overkill )

```
 $arr[$idx]['consignee'] = substr($arr[$idx]['consignee'], 0, -4).'****';
```

For testing

```
 $idx = 0;        
 $arr = [[
     'consignee' => 'someguy'
 ]];

 $arr[$idx]['consignee'] = substr($arr[$idx]['consignee'], 0, -4).'****';

 echo $arr[$idx]['consignee'];
```

Try it [here online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6ae2dc79db4deb98161f11399efbf8a327ef3966)

Comment: It works, but regex is overkill here.

Comment: What if the whole string is less than 4 characters?  Preg_replace won't replace anything -- exposing the name.  Just sayin' maybe adjust the quantifier.