# Replace letters with asterisks except first and last character using MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

How can I Replace letters with asterisks except first and last character
for example: house -> h***e [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVbc8.png)

```
<div id="ld">    
    <?php
    $base=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','exercise');
    $request="select text from exercise";
    /*
       Here I want to show all words from database but with letters replaced
       with asterisks (expect first and last letter)
    */
    mysqli_close($base)
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Is each `text` column value retrieved from your db a collection of words or just one word? What have you tried?

Comment: @nnichols text column contains only one word

Comment: do you want to do it using mysql or php?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey which solution is easier?

Comment: Please add your modified code to you question and say what does or does not work. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Trouble is, if you have a two letter word, there is would be no asterisks applied.  Consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43904214/2943403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do it in mysql. Other answers may give PHP solution, but in mysql:

`SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(text,1), REPEAT('*',LENGTH(text)-2), RIGHT(text,1)) AS text FROM exercise`

simply concatenate the first letter, then your asterisks, then last letter.

Adding the PHP code just in case:

```
// New Connection
$db = new mysqli('localhost','user','pass','database');


$result = $db->query("SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(text,1), REPEAT('*',LENGTH(text)-2), RIGHT(text,1)) AS text FROM exercise");
if($result){
    // Cycle through results
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        echo $row;
    }
    // Free result set
    $result->close();
}
```

alternatively, doing the replacement in PHP 7.1 or later

```
// New Connection
$db = new mysqli('localhost','user','pass','database');


$result = $db->query("SELECT text FROM exercise");
if($result){
    // Cycle through results
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        if (strlen($row) > 2) {
           echo  $row[0] . str_repeat('*', strlen($row)-2) . $row[-1]
        }
        else {
           echo $row
        }

    }
    // Free result set
    $result->close();
}
```

Comment: What happens if the word is one letter long?  What happens if the word is two letters long?

Comment: @mickmackusa in the PHP version, it leaves the original unaltered. In the mysql version, works fine for 2 character string or zero length string. For a 1 character string, it will double it, so 'a' becomes 'aa'