# Replace last 3 characters (at most) with asterisks for multiple elements in each result set row

Tags: php, replace, obfuscation, resultset

I have this PHP code with MySQL database query and I would like to display a record from MySQL database such as `first_name` and `last_name` records, I would like only to display like PHP echo $row the first 3 letters of the first name and last name output, something like this:

```
Joh*** Smi***

Jef*** Joh***
```

```
I saw this example online, I tried it and it works! but just need to replace the example value of '$row = "Hamingway"' to fetch the real array value from MySQL Database instead of: "Hamingway" `Ham****** `**

$row = "Hamingway";
echo (strlen($row) > 3) ? substr($row, 0, 3) . str_repeat('*', strlen($row) - 3) : str_repeat('*', strlen($row));
```

'John Smith' needs to convert to display output ---> 'Joh... Smi...'
'Jeff Johnson' needs to convert to display output ---> 'Jef... Joh...'

I currently presenting rows of data from a MySQL query in an HTML table with the following structure:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['last_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['last_number']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

My current code looks like this:

```
require_once 'includes/db.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM sign_in3 ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 5";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
$records = mysqli_num_rows($results);
if (!empty($records)) { 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) { ?>
        <tr style="font-size:40px;">
            <td><center><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></center></td>
            <td><center><?php echo $row['last_name']; ?></center></td>
            <td><center><?php echo $row['last_number']; ?></center></td>
        </tr>
    <?php }
} ?>
```

I would like to see only the first 3 letters from the first name and last name values.

Comment: So, why you do not use the same code snippet with $row['first_name'] and $row['last_name']?

Comment: Maybe  you'd enjoy [`substr_replace()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77603040/2943403) or some [obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43904214/2943403) I would like to caution you, though, that when you replace letter-for-asterisks, you clue the reader to the exact length of the word being obfuscated -- which IMO is not ideal.  Are you seeking a PHP solution or a MySQL solution -- this distinction will impact which duplicate page I use to close this page.

Comment: Related: [How to mask parts of a string with the asterisk character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44200823/2943403)

Comment: and [Replace letters with asterisks except first and last character using MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70229078/2943403)

Comment: $row = "Hamingway"; the value "Hamingway" is not coming from my MySQL Database, it's a hard coded value. I need the $row = "value from my MySQL Database' to echo out to something like this: <td><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['last_name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['last_number']; ?></td>

Comment: require_once 'includes/db.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM `sign_in3` order by date ASC LIMIT 5
";$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$records = mysqli_num_rows($results);
$alert_msg = "";
}
<?php if (!empty($records)) { while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) { ?> <tr> <tr style="font-size:40px;"> <td><center><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></center></td> <td><center><?php echo $row['last_name']; ?></center></td> <td><center><?php echo $row['last_number']; ?></center></td> </tr> <?php } } ?> 'my echo output is not what I would like to see, I just need the first 3 letters

Comment: It is clean up time. Please delete all of your comments containing code after transferring them to your question body as an [edit].

Comment: That's my current php code, I was wondering if you can work around it? edit my existing code? thank you.

Comment: Please. use. the. [edit]. feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below assume $result is the result of your MySQL query, fetched as an associative array. In this case you would have to adjust the keys accordingly based on your actual database structure.

```
<?php

    $result = [
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Smith'
    ];

    // Process and display the first 3 letters of the first name and last name
    $firstName = $result['first_name'];
    $lastName = $result['last_name'];

    $processedFirstName = (strlen($firstName) > 3) ? substr($firstName, 0, 3) . str_repeat('*', strlen($firstName) - 3) : str_repeat('*', strlen($firstName));
    $processedLastName = (strlen($lastName) > 3) ? substr($lastName, 0, 3) . str_repeat('*', strlen($lastName) - 3) : str_repeat('*', strlen($lastName));

    echo $processedFirstName . ' ' . $processedLastName;

?>
```

Comment: Hi Theo, I will try your code and just a quick question about: $result = [
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Smith'
    ]; is this result pulling from the MySQL database? because I would like it to echo out from the MySQL Database?

Comment: Yes $result is an array of data from your database. I just used hard coded values just as an example.

Comment: <?php
mysql connection
require_once 'includes/db.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM `sign_in3` order by date ASC LIMIT 5";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$records = mysqli_num_rows($results);
?>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>FirstName</th>
</tr>
<?php if (!empty($records)) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
 ?>
<tr>
  <td><center><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></center></td>
</tr>

Comment: That's my current php code, I was wondering if you can  work around it? edit my existing code? thank you.

Comment: That code works! but how could I change the $result = [
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Smith'
    ]; to fetch a real value from MySQL Database?

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that you weren't able to swap in your result set variables with the variables in your posted code and you didn't show how you are iterating your result set, so I guess I'll spell it all out from the querying step. I want to also show you how to more concisely implement your masking logic in a single function call.

Your desired implementation of asterisks does not match your coding attempt, so I'll write my own regex pattern to truncate the name strings after their third character and unconditionally append 3 asterisks.

Code: ([PHPize Demo with dummy data](https://phpize.online/s/Pp))

```
function mask($value)
{
    return preg_replace('/^.{0,3}\K.*/', '***', $value);
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM sign_in3 ORDER BY date LIMIT 5"); 
foreach ($result as $row) {
    printf(
        "<tr>
             <td>%s</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>%s</td>
         </tr>\n",
        mask($row['first_name']),
        mask($row['last_name']))
    );
}
```

From "John Smith" and "Jeff Johnson", you'll get single-column rows.

```
<tr><td>Joh***</td></tr>
<tr><td>Smi***</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jef***</td></tr>
<tr><td>Joh***</td></tr>
```

Comment: require_once 'includes/db.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM `sign_in3` order by date ASC LIMIT 5
";$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$records = mysqli_num_rows($results);
$alert_msg = "";
}
<?php if (!empty($records)) { while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) { ?> <tr> <tr style="font-size:40px;"> <td><center><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></center></td> <td><center><?php echo $row['last_name']; ?></center></td> <td><center><?php echo $row['last_number']; ?></center></td> </tr> <?php } } ?> 'my echo output is not what I would like to see, I just need the first 3 letters

Comment: Well, John, [that commented code is a complete mess](https://3v4l.org/RqPuK) and doesn't resemble the advice that I have carefully crafted for you.  Have you tried to use my snippet?  `mysqli_query($conn, $query)` can be fed directly into a `foreach()` for convenience.  To clarify "what you would like to see", please offer more diverse sample input strings and your exact desired output for each.

Comment: I'm new to this forum and I'm having a hard time showing my PHP codes on here, I'm sorry for the messy output, I tried cut and paste my codes and it's giving me errors? and having me to press Ctrl+k button 'weird' format.

Comment: `Ctrl + K` works fine when you edit your question (which is a good idea when you have clarifying information to give).  Comments are an unsavory place to park code because the formatting is so terrible.  As you can see my 3v4l link in my last comment, sometimes using a 3rd party sandbox to share snippets is handy.  You should delete ALL of your commented code/snippets and transfer them to your question body as an edit.  Make sure that your question only asks ONE question.  Your are allowed to post multiple questions (on multiple pages), but each page must have only one question.

Comment: <?php
mysql connection
require_once 'includes/db.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM `sign_in3` order by date ASC LIMIT 5";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$records = mysqli_num_rows($results);
?>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>FirstName</th>
</tr>
<?php if (!empty($records)) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
 ?>
<tr>
  <td><center><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></center></td>
</tr>

Comment: I was able to paste the whole php code 'well trimmed' just wanted to put it all together, this is my current code. This is the section which I'm having a problem editing to where the output needs to be first 3 letters only showing: <tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></td>
</tr>

Comment: That's my current php code, I was wondering if you can  work around it? edit my existing code? thank you.

Comment: I've updated my answer @John to show you how to implement my advice with your code.

Comment: your codes is awesome sir  and it works great but the value names that are fetching from.my MySQL database are all in one row like joh*** smi*** Jef*** Joh*** Nik*** Tay*** if you could have the values in there own each rows? like row by row would greatly appreciate it and if you could have it displayed like in a table <tr></tr> and <td></td> display, thank you.

Comment: No worries sir, I appreciate your help. The main thing is that it is fetching the data value from.MySQL Database and the rest I can just try to figure it out, again thank you very much