# Replace all characters of a string with asterisks except for the last four characters

Tags: php, string, phone-number, data-masking, redaction

I want to mask the leading digits of a phone number using asterisks.

So that a message can be presented as:

```
Your phone number ********8898 has been sent with a verification code.
```

Comment: `str_replace()`, `substr()` and many moooooore

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Replace Some Characters With Asterisks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272581/how-to-replace-some-characters-with-asterisks)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762251/hint-or-partially-hide-email-address-with-stars-in-php

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545301/partially-hide-email-address-in-php

Comment: How could a possible input string look like? Which kinds of phone numbers should this cover? How would you differentiate between phone numbers and other kinds of numbers, like bank accounts or statistical data?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you wanna mask middle part:

```
private function stringToSecret(string $string = NULL)
{
    if (!$string) {
        return NULL;
    }
    $length = strlen($string);
    $visibleCount = (int) round($length / 4);
    $hiddenCount = $length - ($visibleCount * 2);
    return substr($string, 0, $visibleCount) . str_repeat('*', $hiddenCount) . substr($string, ($visibleCount * -1), $visibleCount);
}
```

**Result:**

- 1 => 1
- 12 => 12
- 123 => 1*3
- 1234 => 1**4
- 12345 => 1***5
- 123456 => 12**56
- 1234567 => 12***67
- 12345678 => 12****78
- ...

Comment: It's better to use multi-byte safe functions.

Comment: This answer doesn't provide the desired result described in the question.

Answer (score 7):

If phonenumber length is more than 4, then you can do this:

```
substr_replace($number, str_repeat('*', strlen($number)-4), 0, -4);
```

If you want to also show the first digit:

```
substr_replace($number, str_repeat('*', strlen($number)-5), 1, -4);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$phone_number = '******' . substr( $phone_number, - 4);
echo $phone_number;
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Using `preg_replace()` will allow you to redact all except the last four characters of a string with an unknown length. This can be suitable as a utility function for all manner of values like phone numbers, credit card numbers, social security numbers, etc.  Match any character which is followed by at least 4 characters and replace it with `*`. [Redacting a portion of an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43904214/2943403) can be a bit more convoluted.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3hVh7))

```
$phone = '040783248898';    
echo preg_replace('/.(?=.{4})/', '*', $phone);
// ********8898
```

---

If you actually need to *find* the 12-digit phone number in the string, then find match the leading 8 digits and look ahead for the remaining 4 digits, then replace the leading 8 digits with 8 asterisks. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/CQ1lL)

```
$msg = 'Your phone number 040783248898 has been sent with a verification code.';

echo preg_replace('/\b\d{8}(?=\d{4}\b)/', '********', $msg);
// Your phone number ********8898 has been sent with a verification code.
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use substr :

```
 $my_text = '12345678';

echo substr($my_text, 1);  // 2345678
```

Comment: This doesn't mask anything, it truncates.

Answer (score -3):

```
*******echo substr("9876543210", 6, 4);
```

Answer (score -4):

```
$email_new = $email_new[0].$email_new[1].$email_new[2].$email_new[3].'******' . substr( $email_new, - 7);
```

Comment: This unformatted answer is missing its educational explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. If possible, please 

[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78197815/edit)

your post to add further details, such as explanations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information in [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) - *"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."*  It might be helpful to review some highly upvoted answers as examples to follow Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).