# How can I hide/replace a part of a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, replace

I want to hide a part of a string using my own function. For e.g: `$string = "hello this is my password";`. If my function is HashPartOfString($string), I want to put my string in this function and have an output like this: `hel***************ord`. How should I do that?

Comment: Perhaps something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200823/how-to-mask-parts-of-a-string-with-the-asterisk-character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you alltime wants to show 1st and last 3 letters and in between some * than you can do it by sub-string and string concat method

```
$str = "hello this is my password"; 
echo substr($str,0,3)."******".substr($str,(strlen($str))-3,3);
```

Comment: $str = "srfegkeruehkgu";
echo substr($str,0,3)."******".substr($str,(strlen($str))-3,3)